# Groups for logged in user are missing

Tags: command-line, permissions, groups

I am seeing a weird issue with my laptop installed with Ubuntu. When I log in and enter a terminal, I am missing groups:

```
~$ groups
ant
```

If I explicitly specify the username, I see all the groups:

```
~$ groups ant
ant : ant adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

The effect this has is that (e.g.) I cannot run docker commands in the shell. However, if I su into a new session, I *do* get the groups and docker commands run fine:

```
~$ su ant
Password: 
~$ groups
ant adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

This only started happening this morning after a fresh reboot, and I'm not sure what I could have done to have broken things. Only thing that stands out is that I installed openvpn prior to the reboot.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be gratefully recieved!

Comment: There is a fix on the duplicate I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the login manager had changed to lightdm (which is possibly mis-configured). Changing back to sddm fixed this issue.